# Inconsistency between manipulation of dummy data vs db data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js

I'm learning Node.js/Express at present and have come across quite a strange problem. I feel at its heart there may be a flawed understanding of copying arrays/objects so I would be grateful for any comments as although I have read into the matter I am stumped.

I have written two functions which basically take an array, manipulate it and return the altered array for further processing/to be forwarded to the client. The code is at https://gist.github.com/grabbeh/8314291 but the general intent can be expressed as follows:

**Works as expected with updated data available on client-side**

```
exports.test = function(req, res){
   returnDummyData(function(data){
        transformData(data, function(data){
             res.json(data);
        });
    });
 }
```

**Original data displayed on client-side in non-transformed state**

```
exports.test = function(req, res){
   returnDBData(function(data){
        transformData(data, function(data){
             res.json(data);
        });
    });
 }
```

I investigated the problem and used dummy data to check the functions as defined within a js file. When using this data it is manipulated by the various functions (adding firstly a ranking property to each object, and then a countryRanking property), and then sent to the client with res.json and is displayed in the altered form.

However, when I extract this data from a MongoDB database using Mongoose and run it through the same functions, when the data is sent to the server it is sent through in an unmanipulated form for reasons I cannot fathom. Stranger still (at least to me), the manipulated form is displayed when accessed directly through console.log but when the whole object is shown through console.log, the unmodified object is shown, as per the following example:

**Function in question**

```
Photo.find({ country:'RUS', tag: 'cat', isVoted: true}, function(err, data){
    calculatePhotoRanking(data, function(data){
        calculateCountryRankings(data, function(data){
            // displayed object does not show ranking or countryRanking properties
            console.log(data[0])
            // however this does display the calculated countryRanking
            console.log(data[0].countryRanking)
            res.json(data)
        });     
    });
})
```

I am puzzled as to how this could come to be frankly. I thought it may be due to not altering the naming of 'data' as it passes through the functions when called, but altering to 'data', 'dataTwo', 'dataThree' makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access and manipulate Mongoose documents as plain JavaScript objects instead of model instances, you can include `lean()` in your query chain:

```
Photo.find({country:'RUS', tag: 'cat', isVoted: true}).lean().exec(
    function(err, data) {
        calculatePhotoRanking(data, function(data) {
            ...
```

Comment: Much obliged. I suspect my question is a duplicate of the question highlighted above but nevertheless you've provided a clear solution. I suspect my knowledge of Mongoose could do with some work! Thanks!